# Как лучше сделать слайдер?

Tags: javascript

Сделал простой слайдер на js. Пока только учусь и многого не знаю, так что реализация оставляет желать лучшего) как лучше его доделать?

```js
var btn1 = document.querySelector(".rad1");
var btn2 = document.querySelector(".rad2");
var btn3 = document.querySelector(".rad3");
var one = document.querySelector(".yellow");
var two = document.querySelector(".green");
var three = document.querySelector(".red");

btn1.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 one.classList.add("block-item-show");
 two.classList.remove("block-item-show");
 three.classList.remove("block-item-show");
})

btn2.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 two.classList.add("block-item-show");
 one.classList.remove("block-item-show");
 three.classList.remove("block-item-show");
})

btn3.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
 three.classList.add("block-item-show");
 one.classList.remove("block-item-show");
 two.classList.remove("block-item-show");
})
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.block {
 position: relative;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: skyblue;
 border: 2px solid #eee;
}

.block-item {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
}

.block-item-show {
 display: block;
}

.yellow {
 background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
 background-color: green;
}

.red {
 background-color: red;
}

.rad1,
.rad2,
.rad3 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 10px;
 z-index: 2;
 margin-left: -50px;
}

.rad2 {
 margin-left: -30px;
}

.rad3 {
 margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="block">
  <div class="block-item yellow"></div>
  <div class="block-item green"></div>
  <div class="block-item red"></div>
  <input class="rad1" type="radio" name="group">
  <input class="rad2" type="radio" name="group">
  <input class="rad3" type="radio" name="group">
 </div>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если работает - больше не трогай)

Comment: Такой слайдер можно и без JS сделать))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сырую получилось как-то так:

```js
var photos = document.querySelectorAll(".block-item");
var btns = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");

btns.forEach(function(item, idx) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    photos.forEach(function(el) {
      el.classList.remove("block-item-show");
    });
    photos[idx].classList.add("block-item-show");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.block {
 position: relative;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: skyblue;
 border: 2px solid #eee;
}

.block-item {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 600px;
 height: 300px;
}

.block-item-show {
 display: block;
}

.yellow {
 background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
 background-color: green;
}

.red {
 background-color: red;
}

.rad1,
.rad2,
.rad3 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 10px;
 z-index: 2;
 margin-left: -50px;
}

.rad2 {
 margin-left: -30px;
}

.rad3 {
 margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="block">
  <div class="block-item yellow"></div>
  <div class="block-item green"></div>
  <div class="block-item red"></div>
  <input class="rad1" type="radio" name="group">
  <input class="rad2" type="radio" name="group">
  <input class="rad3" type="radio" name="group">
 </div>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Наверняка сделать можно еще лучше

---

Но вообще, **такой** "слайдер" можно сделать и без *JS*. Ибо это на слайдер совсем не похоже.

Визуально, минимум:

- Точки изначально при загрузке не хватает на одном из кругляшков
- Слайдер на то и слайдер, чтоб менялся слайдом чтоли или каким-то эффектом. Его сейчас нет.
- Если это для людей слайдер с возможностью тыкать - то должны быть и стрелки для удобства
- Блок `radio` и блок с фото надо обернуть в отдельные `div`'ы, чтоб можно было позиционировать блоками
- Слайдер обычно заводится на таймер по которому меняются фото сами
- Ну а если добавится таймер или стрелки для перелистывания, то придется доделывать еще логику когда фото дойдет до крайнего правого или левого и перелистнется еще раз
- Кмк, лучше открыть популярные слайдеры и посмотреть как там внутри написано. Просто для знаний.

P.S. Как говорят в комментарии: *IE* как обычно впереди планеты всей, поэтому `forEach` лучше заменить на `for` или еще какой-либо цикл, который не умрет в одном из браузеров.

Comment: Я бы вместо `forEach` написал бы `for`. `forEach` на *IE9* уже не работает

Comment: @Yuri пусть он горит синим пламенем)

Comment: Если делать слайдер на css, то можно воспользоваться псевдо-классом checked для отображения начальной точки на слайдере и добавить анимацию с помощью transform. Да и анимацию можно положить в класс и сделать "открытие"(classList.add) класса при клике). Больше интересует логика работы слайдера) как ее можно было улучшить, например добавить переменную и ей бы присваивались значения текущего слайда и не пришлось бы использовать :checked))

Comment: @John-n как по мне это слиииииишком широко описывать разные моменты слайдера. Как я написал последним пунктом, проще взять 3-4 слайдера и посмотреть их устройство. Мозг в начале заступорится, но при этом что-то для себя прояснит

Comment: так и сделаю) спасибо за помощь